# Which build-in libraries of flash can be imported in the FlashFirebug Console?

Tags: flash, firebug

I have just bought FlashFirebug Pro, so I am able to run ActionScript at runtime.
I would like to use the function getDefinitionByName, which comes with flash.utils.*
Somehow i get an error, when I import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName.
Is there a list of supported imports?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlashFirebug uses the D.Eval library, full documentation on how to use it is located here:

http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/